# add custom block inside minicart

Tags: blocks, mini-cart, magento1.9.2.4

I need to display a custom template inside the mini cart, after the subtotal and above the buttons (view all and proceed to checkout). I have my template in /template/mymodule/mytemplate.phtml wich for the moment has only a p tag with 'test' written in it. Then I edited my local.xml to include my template. If I write:

```
<reference name="content"><block type="core/template" name="myname" as="myalias" template="mymodule/mytemplate.phtml" before="-" /></reference>
```

the block is correctly shown at the beginning of the content. But if I change the reference with

```
<reference name="cart_sidebar">
```

nothing is shown in the mini cart.

So, what do I have to reference in local.xml to have my template displayed inside the mini cart?

Comment: are you using `rwd` theme ?

Comment: No, I'm using a custom theme. I know that the rwd theme has a 'promotions' block inside the mini-cart and I can replicate it in my custom theme but to do so I have to edit the mini-cart phtml and insert the promotions block by the getChildHtml fx. I'd like to avoid editing of the template and use only my local.xml to inject my template inside the mini-cart, if that is possible

Comment: no, you can't insert template BETWEEN subtotal and checkout button. You have to override mini-cart phtml and use getChildHtml. But this is normal, no idea why you don't want to override

Comment: I prefer not to override templates if it isn't absolutely necessary. It's just a personal choice to do things, no real reason. I'll override the template, then, thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can provide you the code, if you want

Comment: If you mean the code to override the mini-cart template to put the childHtml function, I already did it by copying what I saw in the rwd theme. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<reference name="cart_sidebar">
    <action method="setTemplate"><file>my_template/file.phtml</file></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: any update on this? were u able to add in minicart?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately, I ended up overriding the mini-cart template with my own, sorry

Comment: how did you override ..please explain..

Answer (score 0):

Override following file in your theme

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

Add following code in  tag.

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
   <referenceBlock name="minicart">
        <block type="core/template" name="myname" as="myalias" template="mymodule/mytemplate.phtml" before="-" />
   </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```